# How, why and when to use the ".Internal" modules pattern?

Tags: haskell

I've seen a couple of package on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html) which contain module names with `.Internal` as their last name component (e.g. `Data.ByteString.Internal`)

Those modules are usually not properly browsable (but they may show up nevertheless) in Haddock and should not be used by client code, but contain definitions which are either re-exported from exposed modules or just used internally.

Now my question(s) to this library organization pattern are:

- What problem(s) do those `.Internal` modules solve?
- Are there other preferable ways to workaround those problems?
- Which definitions should be moved to those `.Internal` modules?
- What's the current recommended practice with respect to organizing libraries with the help of such `.Internal` modules?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Internal` modules are generally modules that expose the *internals* of a package, that break *package encapsulation*.

To take `ByteString` as an example: When you normally use `ByteString`s, they are used as opaque data types; a `ByteString` value is atomic, and its representation is uninteresting. All of the functions in `Data.ByteString` take values of `ByteString`, and never raw `Ptr CChar`s or something.

This is a *good thing*; it means that the `ByteString` authors managed to make the representation abstract enough that all the details about the `ByteString` can be hidden completely from the user. Such a design leads to *encapsulation* of functionality.

The `Internal` modules are for people that wish to work with the internals of an encapsulated concept, to *widen the encapsulation*.

For example, you might want to make a new `BitString` data type, and you want users to be able to convert a `ByteString` into a `BitString` without copying any memory. In order to do this, you can't use opaque `ByteString`s, because that doesn't give you access to the memory that represents the `ByteString`. You need access to the raw memory pointer to the byte data. This is what the `Internal` module for `ByteString`s provides.

You should then make your `BitString` data type encapsulated as well, thus *widening the encapsulation* without breaking it. You are then free to provide your own `BitString.Internal` module, exposing the innards of your data type, for users that might want to inspect its representation in turn.

If someone does not provide an `Internal` module (or similar), you can't gain access to the module's internal representation, and the user writing e.g. `BitString` is forced to (ab)use things like `unsafeCoerce` to cast memory pointers, and things get ugly.

The definitions that should be put in an `Internal` module are the actual data declarations for your data types:

```
module Bla.Internal where

data Bla = Blu Int | Bli String

-- ...

module Bla (Bla, makeBla) where -- ONLY export the Bla type, not the constructors

import Bla.Internal

makeBla :: String -> Bla -- Some function only dealing with the opaque type
makeBla = undefined
```

Comment: Note: This answer should be read in combination with the one given by @luqui

Answer (score 20):

@dflemstr is right, but not explicit about the following point.  Some authors put internals of a package in a `.Internal` module and then don't expose that module via cabal, thereby making it inaccessible to client code.  *This is a bad thing<sup>1</sup>*.

*Exposed* `.Internal` modules help to communicate different levels of abstraction implemented by a module.  The alternatives are:

1. Expose implementation details in the same module as the abstraction.
2. Hide implementation details by not exposing them in module exports or via cabal.

(1) makes the documentation confusing, and makes it hard for the user to tell the transition between his code respecting a module's abstraction and breaking it.  This transition is important: it is analogous to removing a parameter to a function and replacing its occurrences with a constant, a loss of generality.

(2) makes the above transition *impossible* and [hinders the reuse of code](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/encapsulation-considered-harmful/).  We would like to make our code as abstract as possible, but (cf. Einstein) no more so, and the module author does not have as much information as the module user, so is not in a position to decide what code should be *inaccessible*.  See the link for more on this argument, as it is somewhat peculiar and controversial.

Exposing `.Internal` modules provides a happy medium which communicates the abstraction barrier without enforcing it, allowing users to easily restrict themselves to abstract code, but allowing them to "beta expand" the module's use if the abstraction breaks down or is incomplete.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are, of course, complications to this puristic judgement.  An internal change can now break client code, and authors now have a larger obligation to stabilize their implementation as well as their interface.  Even if it is properly disclaimed, users is users and gotsta be supported, so there is some appeal to hiding the internals.  It begs for a custom version policy which differentiates between `.Internal` and interface changes, but fortunately this is consistent with (but not explicit in) the [versioning policy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy).  "Real code" is also notoriously lazy, so exposing an `.Internal` module can provide an easy out when there was an abstract way to define code that was just "harder" (but ultimately supports the community's reuse). It can also discourage reporting an omission in the abstract interface that really should be pushed to the author to fix.

Comment: Then where do you draw the line between code you expose and code you don't? I have used `Internal` modules to allow multiple modules to share components, or to allow a test suite access to the internals. Is that a "bad thing" if I don't expose the module? Wouldn't the logical extreme be that export lists are a "bad thing" because they "hinder reuse"?

Comment: @OmariNorman, are you asking out of curiosity, or are you making an argument?

Comment: Both I suppose :) I suppose you answered this in your footnote when you said that "there is some appeal to hiding the internals".  It seems to me a bit over-broad to say in italics that it's a bad thing to use unexposed `.Internal` modules.

Answer (score 8):

The idea is that you can have the "proper", stabile API which you export from `MyModule` and this is the preferred and documented way to use the library.

In addition to the public API, your module probably has private data constructors and internal helper functions etc. The `MyModule.Internal` submodule can be used to export those internal functions instead of keeping them completely locked inside the module.

- It lets the users of your libary to access the internals if they have needs that you didn't foresee, but with the understanding that they are accessing an internal API that doesn't have the same implicit guarantees as the public one.
- It lets you access the internal functions and constructors for e.g. unit-testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

One extension (or possibly clarification) to what shang and dflemstr said: if you have internal definitions (data types whose constructors aren't exported, etc.) that you want to access from multiple modules which *are* exported, then you typically create such an `.Internal` module which isn't exposed at all (i.e. listed in `Other-Modules` in the `.cabal` file).

However, this sometimes *does* leak out when doing types in ghci (e.g. when using a function but where some of the types it refers to aren't in scope; can't think of an instance where this happens off the top of my head, but it does).