# Is it possible to hide specific functions from appearing in the documentation using haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

I use haddock and don't want all of my exported functions to be displayed in the documentation. Is it possible to hide specific functions?
I found the prune attribute at http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/module-attributes.html, but this is not what I want since some functions which shall be exported don't have a documentation annotation.

Comment: If you're exporting a fuction, why wouldn't you want it listed in the documentation?

Comment: This function is of no use for someone who wants to use this module. However, I need this function in a module for testing and I don't want to copy and paste the source code to this testing module.

Comment: Maybe you could move the code to a hidden module. Then the public module (exposed in cabal terms) and the testing module can both import that module, and the exposed module can hide specific functions by simply not re-exporting them.

Comment: Thank you raymonad, this would be a solution. However this function does not belong to any other module semantically, so I'd still prefer a solution which hides this function from the documentation, it it exists.

Comment: The fact that you're exporting a name alone has effect on the user of your module, since they won't be able to use the same name without explicitly excluding it from the import. In fact, this is good reason to use raymonad's hidden module approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your current module is `Foo.Bar`, one solution would be to break it up into `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Bar.Internal`. You could move all the definitions related to the function you don't want to export--perhaps even *all* the definitions--into `Foo.Bar.Internal`. Then, in `Foo.Bar`, you would re-export only the definitions you want the world to see.

This approach has a couple of advantages. It lets you export everything you need, while still giving the user a clear sign that certain things shouldn't be used. It also lets you document your special functions inside the `Internal` module, which is going to be useful (if only for your future self :P).

You could simply *not* export `Foo.Bar.Internal` in your `.cabal` file, hiding it from the world. However, this is not necessarily the best approach; look at the answers to [How, why and when to use the ".Internal" modules pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190638/how-why-and-when-to-use-the-internal-modules-pattern), in particular [luqui's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198453/286871).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to make a module `Foo.Bar.Hidden` exporting all of the stuff you want to hide, and then re-export the whole `Foo.Bar.Hidden` module from `Foo.Bar`:

```
module Foo.Bar (
  blah1,
  blah2,
  blah3,
  module Foo.Bar.Hidden
)
where
import Foo.Bar.Hidden
blah1 = ...
blah2 = ...
blah3 = ...
```

This way, the hidden stuff will be exported from `Foo.Bar`, but not included in the documentation. The documentation will only include one relatively unobtrusive link to the `Foo.Bar.Hidden` module as a whole.